# Unable to attach file though after you are navigated to files using ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AttachFiles extends Activity {

    Button btnAddFile;
    ListView listViewFiles;
    String[] str;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Adapter myFileListAdapter;
    final int RQS_LOADIMAGE = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAddFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addphoto);
        btnAddFile.setOnClickListener(btnAddFileOnClickListener);

    }

    View.OnClickListener btnAddFileOnClickListener
            = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("file/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_LOADIMAGE);

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case RQS_LOADIMAGE:
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    String string = imageUri.toString();
                    Log.e("STRING", " "+string);

                    arrayList.add(string);

                    Log.e("Get arrayList :" , " "+arrayList);

                    myFileListAdapter = new Adapter(AttachFiles.this, arrayList);
                    listViewFiles = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.filelist);
                    listViewFiles.setAdapter(myFileListAdapter);
                    myFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I can see the files but couldn't load it into ListView.

Answer (score 0):

In case you getting the result inside onactivityresult().I haven't see other than any chance to an error.
**Change Adapter to ArrayAdapter**

```
ArrayAdapter< String > myFileListAdapter = new
ArrayAdapter< String >(AttachFiles.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
```

And declaring listview inside oncreate is better.

And give a try :)